# Many to many relations on same model (mongodb, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

In my mongodb/rails project I have categories and subcategories. Both use same model Category. Each subcategory can belong to more than one category, also category can have more than one subcategory.

Now I don't know how to code this relation to model since I have same model Category on both sides. Also I welcome some example how to code the form view of Category in rails to be able to add subcategories to category.

I use mongoid 2.4, rails 3.2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship here:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :child_categories, class_name: "Category", inverse_of: :parent_categories
has_and_belongs_to_many :parent_categories, class_name: "Catgeory", inverse_of: child_categories
```

A use case:

```
film_category1 = Category.create(name: "French")
film_category2 = Category.create(name: "Spanish")
film_category3 = Category.create(name: "Romantic")
film_category1.child_categories << film_category3
film_category2.child_categories << film_category3

film_category3.parent_categories # [film_category1, film_category2]
film_category2.child_categories # [film_category3]
```

etc.

Comment: Hi, I'm learning mongoid and ruby and I modeled my small application off of this answer. My problem has to do with retrieving things from a parent category ([found here link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718904/how-do-i-retrieve-items-listed-under-this-category-scheme-in-mongoid)) when only the final children categories contain the item. ie, do I have to recursively search downwards from the parent or does mongoid have a solution?