# How do I retrieve items listed under this category scheme in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to create a category/subcategory tree and then search for items that are under a certain category/subcategory. I'm running into the confusion on how I can do that. I have the following code adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016908/many-to-many-relations-on-same-model-mongodb-rails):

```
class Category
    has_and_belongs_to_many :child_categories, class_name: "Category", inverse_of: :parent_categories
    has_and_belongs_to_many :parent_categories, class_name: "Catgeory", inverse_of:  :child_categories

    has_and_belongs_to_many :items
    field :name, type: String

class Item

    field :name, type: String
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

My intended category tree is like this:

```
  |- Clothing
        |-- TShirt
              |--- (Item class) A cool T-Shirt
  |- Books
        |-- Programming
              |--- Databases
                      |----(Item class) Learning MongoDB
                      |----(Item class) Learning PostgreSQL
              |--- Languages
                      |----(Item class) Intro to Ruby Programming
        |-- Cooking
              |--- (Item class) How to bake a cake
```

If all `Category` leaf nodes hold an `Item` (as opposed to having every `Category` hold an `Item`), how would I build the Mongoid query to give me all items that fall under the category **Programming** or **Books**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opted to use mongoid-tree gem instead.